# DriveItem.CreatedBy.Device property is null for files in OneDrive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using Microsoft Graph Client .Net SDK to search for files in my OneDrive. I am searching for all `.docx` files under the root folder:

```
IDriveItemSearchCollectionPage searchResults = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Search(query)
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

The issue is that I need the Device info that created the file but in the Microsoft Graph response the `DriveItem.CreatedBy.Device` property is always null.

How can I retrieve the Device information associated with the `CreatedBy` or `LastUpdatedBy` properties of the `DriveItem`

Could this be due to the fact that I have not registered any device to AAD? Do the devices need to be registered to AAD for Microsoft Graph to retrieve the information of the device that created the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createdBy` property returns the `microsoft.graph.identity` object associated with the file's creation. Which type of identity is returned depends on how the file was created:

- If a *signed-in user* uploaded the file, it will return the `user` identity.
- If an *application without a signed-in user* (i.e. a daemon service) created the file, it will return the `application` identity.
- If a *device without a signed-in user* created the file (i.e. a Surface Hub), it will return the `device` identity.

Comment: Thanks Marc. So is this correct to conclude that Device, User and Application properties are mutually exclusive and only one of them will have a value and the other 2 will be null in the response ? For the case where the signed-in user uploaded the file, is there any way we can get Device information ? The information about the device this signed-in user uploaded the file to OneDrive?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Your application would need to collect that information as part of the upload process.